# What does the field `Memory` mean in `ifconfig`?

Tags: linux, networking, memory, ifconfig

I find a field `Memory` in the result of `ifconfig` command. I am not quite clear about its meaning. By googling, I get some hint from unSpawn's post on [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ifconfig-showing-memory-code-and-ip-checksum-error-670425/) that `Memory` indicate what memory segment is in use. Does that mean a memory-mapping is used to map the NIC to the specified memory segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The network card's onboard memory buffers are mapped into memory so the CPU can copy data into and out of them as the card sends and receives packets.